# Android: How to set Visibility permanently

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, mobile

This is not a duplication from the 'how to setVisibility' questions.

I have an activity 1 and an activity 2, when I start activity 2 I set a layout from Gone to Visible in a Listener and it works, my problem is, when I return to activity 1 and go back into activity 2, the layout's visibility is back to Gone. How do I make the layout stay Visible when I leave it?

Activity2.java:

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

        if (FirstLayout.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            FirstLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
}
```

Activity2.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:visibility="invisible"
      android:id="@+id/oneLayout"
      android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <!-- one Button -->
      <!-- one TextView -->   

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: save your vissiblity state of view in sharedPrefs

Comment: So i guess this is a duplication. My apolegies

Comment: set   android:launchMode = "SingleTop" inside the <activity> element of the activity that holds the layout you want to hide (inside your manifest file),and see what happens

Comment: @Sam added it in the manifest and nothing happend, although when I changed it to "singleTask" it acctaully worked, but the activity took longer to initiate and the animation was diffrent and slower, same thing happend when I changed it to "singleInstance". What does "singleTask" and "singleInstance" really mean?

Comment: @Sam Ok I just read the documentation about it, it doesn't save it if I close the app. Seems like sharedPrefs is the right way to go, thanks tho

Comment: just post my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments above, in your Activity2.java:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

and in the onCreate method at Activity2:

```
 sharedPreferences=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 FirstLayout.setVisibility(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("visibility",false));
```

and then:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FirstLayout.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        FirstLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("visibility",true).commit();
     }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I can use the same SharedPreferences to store the visibility of other layouts, but I have to create a new editor to edit each key right?

Comment: No you can use same editor but you must call comit() whenever you want to save changes.

Comment: I don't think it's working as it should, when I unistall the app and run it again, the Layout is already visible when it shoudn't. Instead of puting a boolean I'm putting an Int, since Visibility is 0, 1 or 2

Comment: During uninstallation of app all sharedpreferences and data will be deleted the matter is android backup servuce that i suggest you disable it during app development time by adding this to manifest file:  android:allowBackup="false"

Comment: its better to use sharedpreferences with unique names related to version of your app

Comment: If you want more discuss open a chat then call me

Comment: I've defined android:allowbackup to false, the problem stands. I'm guessing the problem is in this line `FirstLayout.setVisibility(sharedPreferences.getInt("FirstLayoutV", 1));`
the Int "1" should hold the value `INVISIBLE` according the to documentation but the layout is Visible when I first run the app, something mustn't be correct. I do want to discuss this further, I can't open a chat tho, I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Use sharedPrefrences.getBoolean not int

Comment: `FirstLayout.setVisibility(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("FirstLayoutV", false));` that line gives an error, it says setVisiblity (Int) can't be applied to a Boolean

Comment: I used getBoolean in answer you must save and load appropriate data types

Comment: What do you mean load appropriate data types?

Comment: As you have seen If you need boolean you must save and get boolean. If need int get and put int in sharedpref

Comment: According to the documentation setVisibility holds an Int value of 0(visible), 1(invisible) or 2(gone). With `setVisiblity(sharedPreferences.getInt("key", 1));` it was supposed to be Invisible until I changed the Int to '0' it in an editor in a onClick Listener yet for some reason it's always visible. If you are saying there is a way to set the visibility with a boolean by saving it as a boolean can you please explain it?

Comment: I messed up completely youre right it must take int and if you show your code that gets and puts values i can help more

Comment: I really use sharedPrefrences in my apps and works perfectly im sure your code is somewhere going wrong

Comment: Here is the code:
Inside onCreate:
`sharedPreferences=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  FirstLayout.setVisibility(sharedPreferences.getInt("FirstLayoutV", 1));`
Inside onClick:
`if (FirstLayout.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
  FirstLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
I want it to be Invisible by default, and once i click it it goes visible, and stays visible, I also did set Visibility to Invisible in the xml file hoping it would make a diffrence

Comment: And your onClick method?

Comment: that's it, that's all I have in the onClick regarding that layout, it repeats a few times for more layouts

Comment: Where you used sharedPreferences.putInt() in your onClick method?

Comment: I put it like this: `SharedPreferences.Editor FirstLayoutEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    FirstLayoutEditor.putInt("FirstLayoutV", 0).apply();`
but didn't work. Replacing apply() for commit() didn't work either

Comment: The problem is not the layout staying Visible, it does. The problem is that the layout is already visible before I click the button, when it should be invisible

Comment: It's like the Int '1' in setVisibility is not making it invisible

Comment: Use View.INVISIBLE instead of 1

Comment: Ok that finnaly worked, still I don't understand why '1' doesn't work

Comment: I don't know too and never use values directly it causes sometimes bugs and troubles. But am happy if helped you

Comment: Yap thanks a lot, you probably saved me the whole weekend

Comment: I'm guessing setting `android:allowBackup="false"` would make the app behave like I unistalled it everytime I run it, to make it easier to test SharedPrefs, it's not working, I acctaully have to unistall it, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

you can save your last state via following method

```
boolean mState = false;
final String STATE_VISIBILITY = "state-visibility";

// somewhere in the code assign a value to mState 
// i.e. mState = false (if GONE default) and mState = true (if VISIBLE)

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(STATE_VISIBILITY, mState);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and restore

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore state members from saved instance
    mState = savedInstanceState.Boolean(STATE_VISIBILITY);
    view.setVisibility(mState?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);

    }
```

More on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: How do I define STATE_VISIBILITY and mState? Isn't it supposed to be savedInstanceState.putInt() since visibility values are 0, 1 and 2? Pardon the unexpert questions

Comment: Sure it is your choice you can use putInt if u wanna keep more than two state. I supposed you want to keep VISIBLE or GONE.

Comment: Yea I don't really need more than two states, but how do I create STATE_VISIBILITY and mState?

Comment: These values will be changed in the future by the user, I think using Shared Preferences is a better solution, is it not?

Comment: This method only saves last state during activity transitions. If you want to save the state on app first launched Shared Prefs is the right way. Then use bryan c's method.